# How do I solve this error in my app?

Tags: java, android, xml

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.saptarshi.railwayservices">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_train_black_24dp"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_train_black_24dp"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".splashScreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Index"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_index"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".pnrStatus" />
        <activity android:name=".liveTrain" />
        <activity android:name=".seatAvailability" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_splash_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/launcher"
    tools:context="com.example.saptarshi.railwayservices.splashScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="229dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="Railway Services"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**splashScreen.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Index.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Now when I am running this on my phone it is showing error at line
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);`  in **splashScreen.java**. 
But when I am removing the splash screen then the whole application is running perfectly. I have used thread also to perform. But still showing the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.saptarshi.railwayservices/com.example.saptarshi.railwayservices.splashScreen}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Post logcat error

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Can you remove these lines from the layout 
'   android:background="@drawable/launcher"
    tools:context="com.example.saptarshi.railwayservices.splashScreen" ' and also ' android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" ' from the manifest and try?

Comment: @udit7395 Tried out your way but still getting error

Comment: Did you remove "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" from the manifest ? I mean from splashScreenActivity as well as Index activity as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't use a theme derived from `Theme.AppCompat`. In your `splashScreen`, you're using Activity theme not AppCompatActivity theme when adding the following attribute to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

So, you need to use correct one. You can use:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Then, it should be something like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".splashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

**Note:**
When you don't add the `android:theme` to your activity like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".pnrStatus" />
    <activity android:name=".liveTrain" />
    <activity android:name=".seatAvailability" />
```

It means that the activity implicitly using the Application theme. In your case, the activity will be using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. Which is from the following code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_train_black_24dp"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_train_black_24dp"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  ...

</application>
```